# Django - Display a loading message, popup, screen or icon when clicking a button in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a very simple form:

```
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ form }}
        <div class="row">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Compute">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click this button, depending on the "type" of call, it can takes up to 20 seconds (due to the SQL queries being called)

Is there a way in pure django / python (**please no jQuery, as I try to keep this as simple as possible**) to display anything on the page after clicking the button and until the message is a success ?

Find below my very simple form:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    option1 = forms.BooleanField(label="By XYZ", required=False)
    option2 = forms.BooleanField(label="By ZYX", required=False)

    error_messages = {
        'no_option': "Please select at least one of the options."
    }
```

Note that I also use `messages.success(request, f"Successfully computed values")` which means, somehow the application is aware when the call has ended

Comment: If your view takes 20 seconds, then you should either profile and optimize it or, if the operations being performed are intrisically taking "a lot" (by internet's standards xD) of time, consider using an async task queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. the HTTP protocol is stateless. You would have to implement some Javascript (AJAX) to poll the server until it indicates that the operation (probably running asynchronously) has completed. Which is indeed a lot of work for a small user experience improvement.

I'd go for letting the user poll. "Your results may take up to 20 seconds to generate. Click here to see them"  and back to that same page until the results are indeed ready. This, indeed, requires no Javascript.

This assumes that you spin off the complicated result generation into an asynchronous server operation, so the user is promptly redirected to the results-pending page as soon as he clicks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was expecting this as an answer. That's quite bad... But yes I may go for the second solution you described. Just to have an idea and evaluate that kind of work (also because I am still learning with Django...) Do you know if AJAX integrates well on Django ? as you mentioned. I don't want to work hours and make code unreadable just for this small feature...

Comment: As far as Django is concerned, it receives a GET request from a client and returns a response. That's straightforward. As for the client-side Javascript, that's very far from my area of expertise. It may be straightforward for somebody who spends lots of time coding at that end. For creating asynchronous server threads to crunch data, there are various  well-known packages. Celery is perhaps the best known (also fully-featured, and somewhat complex). There are several others if you search Django-packages. I'm not currently using any of them.